# Averaging values with irregular time intervals

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, data-processing

I have several pairs of arrays of measurements and the times at which the measurements were taken that I want to average. Unfortunately the times at which these measurements were taken isn't regular or the same for each pair.

My idea for averaging them is to create a new array with the value at each second then average these. It works but it seems a bit clumsy and means I have to create many unnecessarily long arrays.

Example Inputs

```
m1 = [0.4, 0.6, 0.2]
t1 = [0.0, 2.4, 5.2]

m2 = [1.0, 1.4, 1.0]
t2 = [0.0, 3.6, 4.8]
```

Generated Regular Arrays for values at each second

```
r1 = [0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.2]
r2 = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.4, 1.0]
```

Average values up to length of shortest array

```
a = [0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 1.0, 0.8]
```

My attempt given list of measurement arrays `measurements` and respective list of time interval arrays `times`

```
def granulate(values, times):
    count = 0
    regular_values = []
    for index, x in enumerate(times):
        while count <= x:
            regular_values.append(values[index])
            count += 1
    return np.array(regular_values)

processed_measurements = [granulate(m, t) for m, t in zip(measurements, times)]
min_length = min(len(m) for m in processed_measurements )
processed_measurements = [m[:min_length] for m in processed_measurements]
average_measurement = np.mean(processed_measurements, axis=0)
```

Is there a better way to do it, ideally using numpy functions?

Comment: Do you want your output to be average at each second or average of shortest array with closest times of other arrays?

Comment: Why do you care about the time if you just want to average the data. Do you want one average for all datasets or an average for each dataset? The problem is not clear.

Comment: I want it to be the average at each second for as long as we have data points for all the mesurement arrays

Comment: @KyleL Do you want closest second or floor second?

Comment: @JoKing, I want the average across the datasets at a regular interval

Comment: @Ehsan I'd prefer to use a floor or ceil consistently

Comment: @KyleL Oh, in that case I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @KyleL please find the edit on my post to reflect floor time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will average to closest second:

```
time_series = np.arange(np.stack((t1, t2)).max())
np.mean([m1[abs(t1-time_series[:,None]).argmin(axis=1)], m2[abs(t2-time_series[:,None]).argmin(axis=1)]], axis=0)
```

If you want to floor times to each second (with possibility of generalizing to more arrays):

```
m = [m1, m2]
t = [t1, t2]
m_t=[]
time_series = np.arange(np.stack(t).max())
for i in range(len(t)):
  time_diff = time_series-t[i][:,None]
  m_t.append(m[i][np.where(time_diff > 0, time_diff, np.inf).argmin(axis=0)])
average = np.mean(m_t, axis=0)
```

output:

```
[0.7 0.7 0.7 0.8 1.  0.8]
```

Comment: So here you create the time series of the desired length, then look up the measurement at the index of the timevalue closest to each time step? Very smart

Comment: @KyleL exactly. I added a loop that can generalize to multiple arrays (I am sure you can even get rid of the loop, but it might solve your issue) and uses floor for time matching.

Answer (score 1):

You can do (a bit more numpy-ish solution):

```py
import numpy as np

# oddly enough - numpy doesn't have it's own ffill function:

def np_ffill(arr):
    mask = np.arange(len(arr))
    mask[np.isnan(arr)]=0
    np.maximum.accumulate(mask, axis=0, out=mask)
    return arr[mask]


t1=np.ceil(t1).astype("int")
t2=np.ceil(t2).astype("int")
r1=np.empty(max(t1)+1)
r2=np.empty(max(t2)+1)
r1[:]=np.nan
r2[:]=np.nan
r1[t1]=m1
r2[t2]=m2

r1=np_ffill(r1)
r2=np_ffill(r2)

>>> print(r1,r2)

[0.4 0.4 0.4 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.2] [1.  1.  1.  1.  1.4 1. ]

#in order to get avg:

r3=np.vstack([r1[:len(r2)],r2[:len(r1)]]).mean(axis=0)

>>> print(r3)
[0.7 0.7 0.7 0.8 1.  0.8]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible solutions:

1. Create a 'bucket' for each time step, lets say 1 second, and insert all measurements that were taken at the time step +/- 1 second in the bucket. Average all values in the bucket.
2. Interpolate every measurement row, so that they have equal time steps. Average all measurements for every time step